# Adding/Subtracting data from databse in single query

Tags: sql, database

Can I add data to existing data of a table and persist it without firing a query to fetch the current data?

For example: I have a `Stock` table, in which I have two columns `itemame(varchar2)` and `stock(integer)`. Suppose initially I have `item1` with stock `10`.

Now can I add 5 to this present 10 directly through a query, without fetching the current stock?

Comment: basic sql: `update yourtable set stock=stock+5 where itemid=1`

Comment: Not sure why this has so many downvotes.  The question is clear, provides an example, and is answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL [UPDATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29) command can refer to existing row values for addition and subtraction.  This is handy, as the update is atomic and thus thread and transaction safe.

You'll probably want something like:

```
UPDATE ItemStock -- Your Stock table
  SET Stock = Stock + 5 -- Increment Stock column by 5
WHERE ItemName = 'item1'; -- Primary Key of your table
```